# If in array knockout js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Is there a way to check if an array contains a certain value, using knockoutJS, within my HTML?

I have the following checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="group" data-bind="checked: $parent.name in groupList" /></td>
```

It would be nice if a certain statement inside my `data-bind` attribute (`$parent.name in groupList`) would work, but obviously it doesn't. With twig it's easy:

```
{% if myVar is in_array(array_keys(someOtherArray)) %}
```

But I cannot find a way to do this with Knockout JS. `groupList` contains an array with names and I would like to check if it contains a certain name. If it does, the checkbox needs to be checked, else not.

Comment: data-bind="checked: groupList().indexOf(ko.unwrap($parent.name)) !== -1"

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: @TSV, Nice solution. No need to invoke `groupList` though. Knockout already provide an `indexOf` method that is unwrapping the value internally. So, `groupList.indexOf(...)` will do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexOf of an observable array:

```
data-bind="checked: groupList().indexOf(ko.unwrap($parent.name)) !== -1"
```